# Prononciation de « fête » au Québec : diphtongaison ou allongement de voyelle ?

Tags: prononciation, québec, phonétique, voyelles

Au Québec on prononce le mot *fête* plutôt différemment de *(vous) faites*. Dans l'article Wikipédia au sujet du [*français québécois*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Voyelles), on indique :

> Les voyelles longues (marquées /ː/) sont **diphtonguées** en syllabe
>   finale fermée : [pɑɔ̯t] « pâte », **[faɪ̯t]** « fête », [ou̯tʁ̥] « autre
>   », [sãẽ̯k] « cinq », [ɡɑʊ̯z] « gaz », [nøy̯tʁ] « neutre », [kaœ̯ʁ] «
>   cœur », etc. L'application de la règle est bloquée sous l'effet de
>   deux contraintes, l'une phonologique, l'autre sociolinguistique. La
>   règle est contrainte :
>
> - phonologiquement, quand l'allongement n'est pas intrinsèque mais dû à    l'action d'une consonne allongeante ou quand la voyelle allongée
>     est [a] <sup>[30](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#cite_note-30)</sup>
>     [...]

À la Banque de dépannage linguistique de l'OQLF on trouve certains de ces mots dans l'article sur la [diphtongaison](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4488) mais pas le mot *fête*, qu'on trouve dans un article sur l'[allongement des voyelles](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4524) :

> L’allongement de certaines voyelles constitue un trait pouvant
>   permettre de distinguer des mots. Ce trait, encore très présent dans
>   le français parlé au Québec, tend toutefois à disparaître ailleurs
>   dans la francophonie.
>  [...]
>   - vous faites [fɛt] *(fèt)* et fête **[fɛ:t]** *(fèèt)*

À première vue, l'API (alphabet phonétique international) et le terme employé pour décrire ce phénomène phonétique diffèrent dans ces deux sources en ce qui a trait au mot *fête*...

---

- S'agit-il de deux interprétations valables du même phénomène ou l'un
  est-il tributaire de l'autre et le cas échéant peut-on expliquer le lien entre la diphtongaison et l'allongement des voyelles ici alors que le premier impliquerait un changement de timbre et pas l'autre ?
- Y a-t-il une graphie à préférer en ce qui a trait à la notation
  phonétique ( [faɪ̯t], [fɛ:t] etc.) ; laquelle est la plus courante,
  la plus précise ?
- Ces deux interprétations/graphies représentent-elles deux
  prononciations distinctes au Québec, par exemple des variations
  régionales ; est-ce qu'on entendrait une différence ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oui, il s'agit absolument de prononciations différentes.

On dit parfois que les prononciations diphtonguées telles que [fajt] sont plutôt caractéristiques de la parole en situation informelle ou de la part de personnes moins instruites. La prononciation [fɛ:t], proche de la norme parisienne de la première moitié du 20e siècle, apparaîtrait plutôt en situation formelle.

En réalité, il s'agit seulement d'une tendance statistique. C'est-à-dire que dans une situation de formalité équivalente, plus une personne est instruite moins souvent elle emploiera la forme diphtonguée, mais le pourcentage de fois où elle l'utilisera sera presque toujours largement supérieur à zéro.

L'autre point important, c'est que les formes diphtonguées des voyelles apparaissant par exemple dans *neutre* et *autre* ne sont pratiquement pas sujettes à une évaluation sociolinguistique négative, alors que les voyelles diphtonguées dans *fête*, *coeur*, *cinq* le sont modérément, et dans *pâte* assez fortement.

Le lien entre le phénomène des voyelles longues et celui de la diphtongaison, c'est que dans les cas où le français - qu'il soit européen ou canadien - a une voyelle longue en syllabe entravée accentuée, le français canadien a tendance à souligner encore davantage la longueur de cette voyelle en la transformant en diphtongue.

La nuance, c'est que le français parisien a perdu la voyelle longue [ɛ:] ailleurs que devant les consonnes allongeantes [v], [z], [R], [ʒ], [vR], et est en voie de perdre la voyelle intrinsèquement longue [ɑ]. Donc les français parisien et canadien ne sont plus toujours en accord sur la présence dans un mot donné d'une voyelle longue.

La principale variation régionale au Québec à ce sujet concerne la diphtongaison en syllabe prétonique. Par exemple, à Montréal et dans l'Ouest on entendra [tRɛ:ne] pour *traîner*, alors qu'à Québec et dans l'Est on peut très bien entendre [tRajne]. Mais partout, par contre, on pourrait dire [tRajn] pour *traîne*.

Comment: Merci ! Généralement pourquoi l'évaluation sociolinguistique varie-t-elle d'un mot à l'autre ?

Comment: C'est que la voyelle diphtonguée varie d'un mot à l'autre. Pour des mots ayant la même voyelle, je crois que l'évaluation sera en général la même. Par exemple, on peut penser à *meute*, *jeûne* et *chanteuse*, qui ont la même voyelle. Cela dit, il serait plausible aussi que le registre du mot influe sur la perception, mais ce n'est pas ce que je voulais dire.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a une forte tendance, dans presque toutes les sources, à mentionner l’existence encore à ce jour au Québec de la distinction des phonèmes [ɛ] et [ɛː], ne se différenciant que par la longueur du son et non par le timbre. On désigne le phonème long par [ɛː] pour perpétuer une distinction historiquement avérée, mais dans le Québec contemporain, ce phonème s’exprime au moyen de deux allophones, qui ont chacun leur domaine d’utilisation particulier.

Si l’on ne considère en un premier temps que le timbre, il existe déjà une variation [ɛ]/[æ] sur le phonème court, le second apparaissant surtout semble-t-il en situations informelles selon Ostiguy et Tousignant<sup>1</sup>, les mêmes locuteurs ajustant leur discours en fonction du contexte. La variante survient sur la voyelle finale d’un mot : [læ] pour *lait*, mais toujours [lɛt͜sje] pour *laitier*.

Si l’on passe maintenant au phonème long, on s’aperçoit que même en situation formelle, dans lequel la diphtongue ne survient habituellement pas chez les locuteurs, le timbre de *fête* n’est pas le même que celui de *faite* à la longueur du son près. Santerre (1976) propose de noter ce son par [ɜː], convention suivie par Ostiguy et Tousignant dans l’opus déjà cité. La position de ce son sur le [graphique des voyelles de l’API](http://ilg.usc.es/ipa-chart/keyboard/) ne m’a guère convaincu que ce soit le choix le plus judicieux, et la consultation du<sup>de la?</sup> [Wikipédia anglais<sup>e?</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_unrounded_vowel) et de son exemple sonore a cristallisé mon doute. Je crois en fait que la prononciation québécoise la plus considérée et la mieux reçue dans le discours formel s’approche davantage de [æː] que de [ɜː] ou [ɛː].

Mais tout cela est finalement de peu de conséquence, puisque ces deux sons (ou ces trois sons, si l’on accepte la notation [ɜː]) servent à représenter la même particularité linguistique : ils ne s’opposent en aucun cas en deux mots différents :

- [æː] est majoritairement utilisé dans une syllabe en précédant une contenant un *e* caduc.

  - **fête** [fæːt]
  - **traître** [tʁæːtʁ]
  - **chèrement** [ʃæːʁmã]
- [ɛː] le côtoie dans les autres mots, le choix dépendant en partie de la région d’origine du locuteur, tel que décrit dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/30694/13100), l’Est du Québec, à partir des environs de la ville de Québec, utilisant davantage le son [æː], l’Ouest le son [ɛː].

  - **bêler** [bɛːle]/[bæːle]
  - **freiner** [fʁɛːne]/[fʁæːne]
  - **ferrer** [fɛːʁe]/[fæːʁe]
  - **pêcher** [pɛːʃe]/[pæːʃe]
  - ...et pour bien **mêler** ([mɛːle]/[mæːle]) les choses, le verbe ***fêter*** [fɛːte]/[fæːte] fait aussi partie du groupe...

Le phénomène de l’allongement du son [ɛ] (peu importe le timbre qu’il prend) est applicable à la très vaste majorité des locuteurs francophones du Québec, autant dans le discours très familier que dans les situations les plus formelles, et ce à tous les échelons de la hiérarchie sociale.

Quant à la diphtongaison de ce son dans le mot *fête*, qu’on la note [faɛ̆t], [faɪ̆t] ou [fæɪ̆t] (trois variantes qui sont probablement chacune utilisées si l’on considère la population québécoise dans son ensemble), elle survient plutôt dans le discours informel, et n’est pas le fait de tous les Québécois, au contraire. Les études citées par Ostiguy et Tousignant montrent qu’elle est davantage présente chez les gens occupant un emploi n’exigeant que peu de scolarité, et qu’elle est même publiquement condamnée par une partie de la population, en faisant foi son inscription dans les programmes québécois d’enseignement du français de 1959 et 1968 comme l’un des phénomènes langagiers à corriger chez les élèves.

Deux phénomènes distincts, donc.

On notera que si le mot *fête* est absent de l’un des articles de la Banque de dépannage linguistique cités dans la question originale, le mot *père*, lui, est présent dans les deux, et qu’il y reçoit un traitement différent selon le trait de langue présenté :

- [père (paèr)](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4488) lorsqu’on traite de la diphtongaison ;
- [père (pèèr)](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4524) quand on discute de l’allongement des voyelles.

De ceci je conclus qu’il ne faut pas extrapoler qu’il y a déni de la réalité de la diphtongaison dans *fête*, mais plutôt simplement que les exemples cités ont été jugés suffisants.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Le français québécois, Normes et usages, Luc Ostiguy & Claude Tousignant, première édition 1993 (une nouvelle édition datée de 2008 avec mises à jour existe, mais n’a pas été consultée).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour. Par le passé, les Français disaient [fɛːt]. Maintenant, la majorité des Québécois disent [faɪ̯t], mais il y a des Québécois qui disent [fɛɪ̯t]. Les spécialistes ont considéré que [faɪ̯t] est une prononciation non-standard, parce que ce n'est pas tout le monde qui prononcent comme ça et parce que [faɪ̯t], ce n'est pas proche de [fɛːt], et ils ont décidé que [fɛːt] et [fɛɪ̯t] sont tous standard, parce que la différence entre [fɛːt] et [fɛɪ̯t] il n'y a pas une grosse différence; ajoutons que le personnel d'antenne de Radio-Canada prononce [fɛɪ̯t].